# how to split the data as RDD[(String,Array[String])] in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

my sample code is :

```
val labledPoints = RDD[Array[String]].mapPartitions(
       iter => {
          iter.map(row => {
             val label = row(classIndex)
             val features = row.take(classIndex) ++ row.drop(classIndex + 1)
            (label, features)
            })
      })
```

I want to split data from classindex in this format but my code takes time for big data. Is any other way to find it?

Comment: What are you going to do with the RDD after you've made a PairRDD of it?

Comment: How long does it take? How big is your data set and what type of machine or cluster are you running on? The map operation in itself shouldn't take long, so as @TheArchetypalPaul also asks above, what are you doing afterwards? (Also I'm wondering why you use `mapPartitions` instead of just `map`?)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt  mapPartition is better than map . Also I am not using mb data set . These are used to code id3 decision tree

Comment: map converts each element of the source RDD into a single element of the result RDD by applying a function. mapPartitions converts each partition of the source RDD into into multiple elements of the result.

Comment: @AkhilaV, no, `mapPartitions` is not better. I don't see any compelling reason here to use it over `map`. You're not using anything that would require to use `mapPartitions`, so go with `map`.

Comment: I agree with @Reactormonk. `mapPartition` is only better if you need to do some "heavy" operation, like say opening a DB-connection, which you want to do as few times as possible. In your case, you simply have to apply a trivial function to every row in your dataset.

Comment: But back to the original question - I do not understand your answer "Also I am not using mb data set". What does that mean? I'm asking how much data is in your RDD and what sort of operation are you performing afterwards on your `labledPoints`. Do you call `reduceByKey`? `join`? `collect`?

Comment: Any other way faster than my sample code ?

Comment: i am using more than one gb dataset. So with my code  this labledPoints itself take 3 minutes to complete.I already told that this is used to code id3 decision tree.So need to compute some calculations like entropy information Gain and all.

Comment: Is any way to find it faster than my code !